# How do I get varying user input from same input line?

Tags: c++

For example, if one were to enter scores 10 13 14 18 (or varying amount) on a single line then one could add those inputs and then find the average.

How does one do this?

Comment: Read a line, split it, convert into integers (`std::stringstream` may come to help) and do whatever you want.

Comment: _"How do I get varying user input from same input line"_ sounds like you want to shuffle the input? Or do you want to find the average? I interpret this as two very different questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the best & simple way to achieve it. The following program takes a number of arguments from the user (pattern: `main.exe <args...>`) and fills the array to sum up then it adds all the values and evaluates the average.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        sum += atoi(argv[i]);
    }

    std::cout << "Average: " << (sum / 2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps you.